# How to migrate lightswitch application with windows authentication to antother web server

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I created Lightswitch application with windows authentication enabled and it works as I expect. I have a problem when I want to migrate application to another server.

1.
I move appliaction files to another server, but database stay on the same sql server:
In this case, application requires windows username and password and doesn't allow me to log in authomatically. Also, when I type username and password, it doesn't recognize my windows account.

2.
I move application filse to another server and move database to another sql server and update web config file properly. Now I just get "access denied" error message in my browser when I try to open application.

What is solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try LightSwitchSecurityAdmin.exe tool in the Lightswitch folder to set new user account.
Lightswitch creates user and authorization tables in the SQL "Intrinsic Data" database, and I think you have to map it to the user of the server you are moving the application to.

Some examples of command line usage on [Beth Massi Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/03/23/deploying-lightswitch-applications-to-iis6-amp-automating-deployment-packages.aspx)

[image: List of files required to run Lightswitchsecurityadmin from any folder]